Codes with low error-control rate
Suppose that $C \subset \mathbb{F}_2^n$ is a code, and let $d = d(C) = \min\{d(x,y): x,y\in C\}$ the minimum distance of $C$, where $d(\cdot, \cdot)$ is the Hamming distance. We can define $r = \frac{d-1}{n}$ to be the error-control rate of the code. Suppose further, that we can't add any more codewords $w \in \mathbb{F}_2^n$ to $C$ such that $d(C \cup \{q\}) = d$
Intuitively speaking, it seems clear that such a code should not be too useful. What I mean by this is even though the information rate of the code might be high, it feels like the low error control rate should imply that the probability of transmitting a message so that it can be decoded properly is so low, that in expectation the high information rate becomes useless. Is there a way to prove this?

did you see my answer

There is no physical or application related meaning to the "rate"
$$
\frac{d-1}{n}
$$
you define. Your quantity $d-1$ (before dividing by $n$) is, however, the error detection capability of the code.
There is always a tradeoff between the size (number of codewords) $|C|$ and the minimum distance $d$, such as given by various bounds, Hamming, Singleton, Gilbert-Varshamov, etc.
You are right that if the code is maximal in the sense you state, it is a good code. However, the channel conditions under which the code is to be used is what determines the choice of $d$ and then the maximization of the number of codewords, or even more generally, considering codes with efficient decoding algorithms etc.
Assuming you are correcting random, independent errors, with probability of error per symbol given by some $p,$ then on average there are about $np$ errors  per code blocklength $n,$ thus you should be looking for a code of minimum distance somewhat larger than $2np$ if you want to correct most errors.
If you want to only degtect errors then you should look for a code of minimum distance somewhat larger than $np.$
